# Profile (quasi-)likelihood score tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood, quasi-likelihood, profile-likelihood, quasi-maximum-likelihood

Suppose I have a log-likelihood or quasi-log-likelihood for my data in terms of the parameter vectors $\theta$ and $\psi$:
$$L(\theta;\psi)=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T{\log{f(y_t|\theta;\psi)}}.$$
(I am interested in both the log-likelihood case, and the quasi-log-likelihood case. Being a quasi-log-likelihood means that $f$ is not necessarily the PDF of the true DGP.)

I am only interested in testing $\theta$, so I construct the profile-(quasi-)log-likelihood:
$$\tilde{L}(\theta)=\max_\psi{L(\theta;\psi)}.$$

Let:
$$\psi^*(\theta):=\arg\max_\psi{L(\theta;\psi)}.$$

Is it possible to compute a valid score test for $\theta=\theta_0$ just using information on the first and second derivatives of $\tilde{L}$ or $\log{f(y_t|\theta;\psi^*(\theta))}$ ($t\in\{1,\dots,T\}$) in terms of $\theta$? Is it harder in the quasi-likelihood case?

---

A few notes:

This document gives a profile log-likelihood score test [https://web.stat.tamu.edu/~suhasini/teaching613/chapter3.pdf](https://web.stat.tamu.edu/%7Esuhasini/teaching613/chapter3.pdf), but the asymptotic distribution is given in terms of the second derivatives of $L$ not $\tilde{L}$.

This document [https://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~ckuan/pdf/et01/ch9.pdf](https://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/%7Eckuan/pdf/et01/ch9.pdf) suggests that when testing equality of all parameters (so $R=I$ in their notation), then the quasi-likelihood score test collapses to a standard score test using the outer-product of gradients matrix rather than the Hessian.

(The last result is slightly surprising as https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0165176583900484 suggest that the outer-product of gradients form of the score test is not very robust!)

Comment: No, I don't believe it is possible to compute the score test for $\theta$ from the profile likelihood and its derivatives. The second derivative of $\tilde L$ gives conditional observed information for $\theta$ whereas the score test needs conditional expected information.  Profile likelihoods are used to complete likelihood ratio rests rather than score tests. I must say it is difficult to understand why you would want to do this since it is almost always easier to compute the score test directly from the likelihood rather than from the profile likelihood.